# How to maintain original file name after compile in Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I’m using next framework version 11.1.2 and I’m quite new to it. Does anyone knows how to maintain the original file names after compile and the pages being served?

Example:
I have an image called: frontend-desktop-logo.png
But after compile, it’s change to: frontend-desktop-logo.f4735b2f97bf9b97dd8bbee4ea16928d.png

I suspect that I need to change something on the next.conig.js file. I’ve tried this configuration:

```
generateEtags: false,
```

But didn’t seem to work. My other though would be on applying some change on the webpack configuration. I searched the web for it, but didn’t find anything.

Comment: The reason for generating unique names is to take care of caching, generating net new file names is your best bet against aggressive caching by browsers and proxies - do you have a reason not to change the names ? If not a concern, you could just refer them straight from a remote path and not import the image in js avoiding the bundling behavior

Comment: Yeah, for example: I can´t reference the image on the meta tags open graph, If I don´t know exactly what the image name is going to be.

Comment: Can't you serve the image from the `public` folder in your Next.js app and reference it from there? See [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Comment: It´s not exactly what I had in mind, but I managed to setup similar to my initial intention. Inside the public folder, I have a subfolder for the images, like so:
public/somefolder
I dint´t want to hard code this subfolder on the app code. Not only for security reasons, but also because it could change in the future. So I created an "alias" in the next.config.js, like so:
      {
        source: '/files-layout/:files',
        destination: '/somefolder/:files',
      }
Seemed to work fine, but I would still want to know if it´s possible to maintain the original file name on the compile.